# Register 1 event with many calls or register multiple events?

Tags: javascript, performance, dom-events

Performance wise, is it better to register one single event with an array of functions to call or just register a different event for each function that need to be called? I can't seem to find an answer on google

An example:
given these functions

```
function doA(){ /* do A */};
function doB(){ /* do B */};
function doC(){ /* do C */};
```

is it better to do this

```
var funcs=[];
funcs.push(doA);
funcs.push(doB);
funcs.push(doC);
$(window).on("resize", function(){
    for(var i=0; i<funcs.length; i++){
        funcs[i]();
    }
});
```

or this

```
$(window).on("resize", doA);
$(window).on("resize", doB);
$(window).on("resize", doC);
```

I am using jQuery in this example but the same thing might be asked for pure Javascript.

Mind that this is just an example, In my real applications Functions/events are added/removed dynamically during execution.

EDIT: While i agree that the best approach is to have a single function that calls the others, this is just an example of two other approaches that have to be used in other situations, that is when you don't know in advance how many functions you have that will listen to an event. In this case is it better to have a listener for each function or create a global listener that does the call?

Comment: If there are no Asynchronous functions getting called from within these functions then why don't you simply call B inside A and call C inside B, then you can have $(window).on("resize", doA);

Comment: this is just an example, In my real applications Functions/events are added/removed dynamically during execution.

Answer (score 0):

Common design principles would suggest that:

```
smallFunc1(string) {}
smallFunc2(string) {}

bigFunc1(string) {
    smallFunc1(string);
    smallFunc2(string);
}
```

is more sensible than looping through each function. That seems like unnecessary extra steps & defined variables.

Comment: Maybe i should've specified that the number of functions that need to be executed/event listeners is not static and will be added/removed while the user is browsing on the site

Answer (score 0):

Agree with JBux, the array approach seems like overhead and also makes it more difficult to understand what's going on.

Performance wise, I think the actions that are performed in `doA`, `doB`... are more relevant and not necessary the way you call them.

A common way to do initialization and register events is to use the Module Pattern and use the `init` function for the setup.

```
function library(module) {
  $(function() {
    if (module.init) {
      module.init();
    }
  });
  return module;
}

var myLibrary = library(function() {
   return {
     init: function() {
       /*implementation*/
     }
   };
}());
```

Interesting resource: http://addyosmani.com/largescalejavascript/

Comment: ok, but what if you don't know in advance which functions need to be called during an event? Is it better to make a listener to each one or to be called by a single listener?

Comment: Single listener makes more sense for me initially.

This would be responsible for the logic that gets the actions you want to perform and keep it centralized.

Different listeners could work but can be more difficult to manage later.

Comment: Another thought about using the array to track the functions you need to call.

This implies you will be changing the the array on certain actions and passing it around a as a global ?

I would consider getting the list of actions once on the event listener (centralized logic) instead of changing the array every time the user does something, if you have the information that allows you to determine what functions you want to call.

Comment: I didn't want to add useless details in the question but i'm doing this in a angular application. I have made a service that keeps track of the window's height and handles the resize event (debounced). The service contains an object (not an array) with all the functions he needs to call, a directive can register to the service (and will be given an id) and then when it's removed it will trigger a $scope.on('$destroy') event where it will unregister from the service deleting the function from the callbacks list object